# How to do with large groups in spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I have used `groupByKey(): RDD[(K, Iterable[V])]` to split a RDD to groups. And each group is still large. How to do with each group, for example, how to sort it? Shall I create a new RDD for each group?

Comment: large=? And if you "do something" after group by, you should use reduceByKey or aggregateByKey

Comment: what specific problems with these *large* groups? I think you can still sort them even if it is large.

Comment: I need do some pattern matching on each group, but before that, I need a sorted group. So my problem is sorting. How to sort Iterable? Shall I create a list from Iterable, or create a RDD?